# JSON serialization except for embeds_one objects in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization, mongoid

Given this mongoid "Report" Document object that embeds_one location object:

```
{
  comment: "",
  location: {
    address: "391 Little Bourke St, Melbourne VIC 3000, Australia",
    geocode: {
      ll: "-37.813787,144.961227",
    }
  },
  _id: "4d84af7f52f3d40539000021",
}
```

How do I except the geocode part of the location hash?

As an example, it's easy to except the comment field by doing this in the Report model:

```
def to_json(options={})
  options[:except] ||= :comment
  super(options)
end
```

What's the code look like to except "geocode", which is part of location?

Comment: Did you try to do the same for the Location class, e.g. :except => :geocode?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongoid'

Mongoid::Config.settings = {
  "host" => "127.0.0.1",
  "database" => "testing"
}

class Report
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :location

  field :comment
end

class Location
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :address
  field :geocode, :type => Hash

  embedded_in :report
end

report = Report.new(:comment=>'comment', :location => {:address=>'elm street', :geocode => {:ll=>'-31'}})
puts report.to_json(:include=>:location, :except => :geocode)
```

yields:
{"_id":"4dab2655b4e4cf2fa6000001","comment":"comment","location":{"_id":"4dab2655b4e4cf2fa6000002","address":"elm street"}}

and if you want the Location always omit the geocode, then you should re-define the serializable_hash inside Location class:

```
  def serializable_hash(options = nil)
    options ||= {}
    options[:except] = :geocode
    super(options).tap do |attrs|
      serialize_relations(attrs, options) if options[:include]
    end
  end
```